# Почему settimeout вызывает старое значение функции

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function abc () {
  alert (123);
}
setTimeout(abc, 2000);

abc = null;
```

Здравствуйте, почему setTimeout выведет старое значение функции, если функция это объект и мы передаем её аргументом в setTimeout "по ссылке", а не как копию примитива?

Comment: выводит 123б а что должно выводиться?

Comment: Я ожидаю null, т.к. через 2000 ms значение abc изменилось на null, а любая функция это прежде всего объект, потому обращение идет к этому объекту, а не его копии как в случае с примитивом.

Comment: да, но ссылка в функцию уже передана, а обнуляете вы ее в другой обасти видимости

Comment: Так я передаю ссылку, а не саму функцию, соответственно setTimeout будет искать её не в своем lexical environment, а через [[scope]] будет брать из вне window.abc, которая на этот момент уже будет null.

Comment: Не будет setTimeout ничего искать через 2 секунды. Он запомнил переданную ссылку и просто вызовет функцию.

Comment: Возможно вы путаете с вариантом когда передаётся строка, тогда действительно поиск будет в момент исполнения, но я совершенно не помню в каком скоупе будет поиск и даже гуглить не буду, т.к. этого делать просто не нужно никогда

Answer (score -1):

Примерно разобрался, если бы мы "мутировали" объект, например после setTimeout писали бы

```
abc.value = 5
```

в таком случае, setTimeout выполнился бы с обновленной функцией abc, у которой уже есть ключ value. Но при присваивании null, мы как бы создаем новый объект под старым именем abc, но при этом ссылка на старый abc остается в lexical environment setTimeout-а, потому он выведет старый объект abc. Упрощенный вариант:

```
a = { name: 'Я объект' }
b = a; // теперь a и b ссылаются на одно место в памяти

console.log (a) // { name: 'Я объект' }
console.log (b) // { name: 'Я объект' }

a = null // под a выделяется новое место в памяти
console.log (a) // null, в b осталась ссылка на старое место в памяти
console.log (b) // { name: 'Я объект' }
```

Comment: Нет там никакого lexical environment